# How to stop a WPF app if the app is minimized, on background or the user is idling?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a Window application in WPF, and I want to close the application when the user is idling or the app is minimized or in the background. Close the window if the user is not using the app in summary. I want to close the window if the app has been 2 minutes without being used.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Maybe write a UWP application instead. It offers such a suspend behavior out of the box. In WPF you have to implement it yourself. Basically subscribe to input events (keyboard, mouse) and start/reset a timer in the event handlers. If the elapsed time of the timer exceeds a certain threshold e.g., 2000ms you shutdown the application. Handle the `Window.StateChanged` event to get notified when the window was minimized.

Comment: I cannot change to UWP, the project is already working with WPF

Comment: Why you need that? What if user will expect the app opened after 3 minutes? It will look as the app was crashed and closed unexpectedly.

Comment: How is that relevant to answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add an eventhandler to the Window.Deactivated Event (create new Eventhandler in the Properties window or add it in your XAML)

`Deactivated="Window_Deactivated"`

2. create a 2 minute timer in the eventhandler

   ```
    private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {

        //create a timer
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        //When the timer runs out, this eventhandler gets called
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);

        //timer ends in 2 mins
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);

        //timer starts
        timer.Start();    
    }
   ```
3. close the application in the Timer.Tick event

   ```
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {

        //Application closes
        this.Close();
    }
   ```

Comment: The OP has specifically asked _"to close the application when the user is idling"_. The above doesn't in any way do that. If you're going to write all the code for the question's author, you need to write the code they ask for. You really shouldn't be answering such broad questions in the first place, but if you're going to do so, at least put in the effort required to do it right.